# How to plot a dataframe in polar coordinates?

Tags: dataframe, polar-coordinates

I have a dataframe where the columns are polar angles, and the rows are radius. So each case of this df contains the value (a temperature) of the region (r, theta)=(row, column).

Do you know how to represent it on a cylindrical graph (if possible using plt.imshow)?

I've already tried this:

```
ig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5));
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar');
ax.imshow(df_power)
```

which produces

[image]

not at all what I expected to happen....

Thanks a lot.